# Installation failed on device, debugging (Battery ??)

Tags: android, eclipse, failed-installation

I'm starting to learn Android's development. I have my first code, and I want to try it in mi Samsung Galaxy S3 with Eclipse but I have the next Error in the LogCat when I try in Run Button.

```
03-03 20:15:26.733: E/Watchdog(2301): !@Sync 389
03-03 20:15:42.308: E/MtpService(21129): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
03-03 20:15:42.308: E/MtpService(21129): battPlugged Type : 2
03-03 20:15:42.368: E/WifiHW(2301): ##################### set firmware type 0 #####################
03-03 20:15:46.673: E/WifiHW(2301): ##################### set firmware type 0 #####################
```

What type of error is it? I have read another posts but I don't find anything with battPlugged error.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I get identical `E/MtpService` errors non-stop on other Samsung Galaxy devices. I guess Samsung just does not care about the logcat spam that developers for their device have to wade through.